# include node_modules when using git worktree

Tags: git, node-modules, git-worktree

I have a big node repo that has a `node_modules` folder, which is untracked (included in the `.gitignore` file). I recently started learning about git worktrees and I would like to be able to add worktrees that include the `node_modules` folder without having to run npm install on that worktree. Is there a way to accomplish that without editing `.gitignore` or copying the folder manually? I just would like to have worktrees ready to go when creating them

thanks in advance

searched for related questions, checked the documentation of git worktree

Comment: Short answer: no. Slightly longer: it's not a good idea in general since your added working tree on some other branch might use *different versions* of various npm modules. If you're sure you will be using the same ones, you can of course do the copy-manually step. I would avoid committing these files as once something is committed in Git, it is saved forever (well, by default: it's sometimes possible to get rid of these, but it can be very difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you can temporarily remove `node_modules` from `.gitignore` and add that line back after you've pushed the contents upstream.

Comment: This violates the OP's "without editing `.gitignore`" step, and once you've added and committed the node modules files and pushed them to GitHub, you're stuck with them forever (assuming GitHub is the upstream; GitHub never delete any commits no matter how hard you work on your end).

Answer (score 0):

So there's not a way, that I can think of, that accomplishes what you're asking without violating at least one of your prerequisites. You will have to do one of the 3:

1. Run `npm install` within your worktree.
2. Manually copy `node_modules`.
3. Temporarily remove `node_modules` within your `.gitignore` (this would run into the issue of having to remove previously tracked `node_modules` from git).

I would recommend the first (run `npm install` within your worktree), for the exact reason that @torek stated. There could be slightly different versions of dependencies within your `node_modules` and unless it matches 1:1 to your `package_lock.json` within the worktree, you're in for a world of frustration and you'll end up running `npm install` anyways.

The main use case I have for a worktree is because I am working on a feature branch that has a different set of node_modules (say an angular version upgrade feature branch) and I need to checkout develop or another feature branch for a code review and I don't want to have to run `npm install` every time I checkout to a new branch.